# jQuery getJSON with Django sending wrong sessionid cookie

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, json, cookies

Been having an issue with getJSON in which it sends the wrong value for Django's sessionid cookie.

I have an API running on port 8000. At this URL: http://localhost:8000/api/accounts/banner , it returns a JSON document if there's a user logged in, otherwise it returns a 404 code. The API works without problems when I access it via the web browser directly, but I have a client app running on port 8888 that runs the following code:

```
$(function() {

  window.APIConfig = {
    providerURL: "http://localhost:8000/",
    endpoint: "api/accounts/banner",
  }

  callback = function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }

  $.getJSON(
    APIConfig.providerURL + APIConfig.endpoint + "?callback=?",
    callback
  )
});
```

Here I get a 404 response, because the request that getJSON sends contains the wrong value for the sessionid cookie that Django requires. The request headers for when I access the URL directly are:

```
Cookie: csrftoken=42f709f871a99b8c514dc70c68418a1f; sessionid=958605eefdb46c516b101f5f5893474a
```

but the AJAX request sends this:

```
Cookie: csrftoken=42f709f871a99b8c514dc70c68418a1f; sessionid=c312d7a234c03f1a0cd8f878fae2b325
```

What's more, the server response contains a new cookie:

```
Set-Cookie:sessionid=c56f37c9dcd8d699f949c488163ccf4c; expires=Fri, 16-Dec-2011 22:52:39 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
```

So when I access the URL directly again, I get a 404 in the browser too.

Why does AJAX send a different cookie and where is that coming from?

Answer (score 0):

There's the (rather obvious) fact that both apps (on port 8000 and 8888) set a cookie called sessionid, both being Django apps. AJAX loads the cookie values for the remote domain before sending it's request, I can see that some extra cookies that I set are indeed being sent, but it appears that if it finds that it already has a value for any one cookie it is trying to load, it ignores that value and sticks to what it already has. That's really the problem.

I will ask this properly in a separate question.